# GET_FAILURE in reducer test returns wrong in received

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

```
 describe('get postals failed', () => {

    it(`it should handle ${GET_POSTAL}`, () => {
      const code = 'fail';
      expect(reducer(state, { type: GET_POSTAL, code })).toEqual({
        ...state,
        code,
        loading: true,
      });
    });

    const payload = {
      error: {
        errorMessage: 'test',
        postalInfo: {},
      }
    };

      state = reducer(state,{
        GET_POSTAL_FAILED,
        payload
      });

      expect(state).toEqual({
        ...state,
        error: payload.error,
        loading: false,
      });
    })
```

Actual reducer:

```
case constants.GET_POSTAL_FAILED:
  return {
    ...state,
    error: action.payload.error,
    loading: false,
  };
```

In the error:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

- Expected
+ Received

Object {
-   "error": Object {
-     "errorMessage": "test",
-     "postalInfo": Object {},
-   },
-   "loading": false,
    "postalInfo": Object {},
}
```

I've tried different things but it refuses to bring the error message..

Comment: It seems that when you are calling the reducer with `GET_POSTAL_FAILED` you are not setting it in the `type` attribute (i.e. `reducer(state, { type: GET_POSTAL_FAILED, payload });`). Also, you should place every call to the `reducer` inside an `it`.

Comment: @mgarcia ah ofc... i didnt see that lol. Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you are calling the reducer with `GET_POSTAL_FAILED` you are not setting it in the `type` attribute:

```
reducer(state, {
    type: GET_POSTAL_FAILED,
    payload
});
```

Also, you should place every call to the `reducer` inside an `it`.